Why stepping debug failed with cc2538dk on Contiki-NG, but success on RIOT?
I have a question about debugging with cc2538 on Contiki-NG.
I'm testing the 6LoWPAN function on both RIOT and Contiki-NG. While stepping through the code during debugging, RIOT works fine, but Contiki-NG fails - the application is just hello-world example.
I'm using the same debugging method for both:

First, I connect JLink to the SmartRF06+cc2538EM.
Then, I open JLinkDebugServer in one session and gdb in another.

When the gdb connection is established for Contiki-NG, it shows that the code steps into 0xdeadbeef. The JLinkDebugExe outputs:
Reading common registers: ERROR: Cannot read register 0 (R0) while CPU is running
Read register 'r0' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0xEFBEADDE
ERROR: Cannot read register 1 (R1) while CPU is running

Has anyone encountered this problem?
Any insights related to this problem or helpful information would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Dingisoul
how to fix contiki-ng to support stepping debugging? Are there any other debugging method? what part of configuration influence this problem? Why RIOT can success but Contiki-NG not?

Always read error/diagnostic messages from the top.  It seems likely the the fundamental issue here is:
Reading common registers: ERROR: Cannot read register 0 (R0) while CPU is running

Given that statement, the value "read" from the register is not valid.  It certainly does not indicate:

... that the code steps into 0xdeadbeef.

It indicates that the debugger has not halted the processor, has no control of it, and cannot read registers in that state.
Most debuggers have a "Connect Under Reset" or similar option. That may solve your problem, but whatever the issue is not related to the use of any particular RTOS - the debugger is entirely agnostic to what code is running - but everything to do with your debugger configuration which you have not elaborated on.

Thanks, Clifford. Sorry for missing information in my question. I have solved it and post the answer below.

I’ve discovered the root cause of the issue. Contiki-NG enables the watchdog timer by default.
When stepping through the code during debugging, it triggers the watchdog timeout, causing the entire system to reboot and resulting in the debugger fail.
I comment out the watchdog code, and now the debugger is working properly.
RIOT do not use cc2538’s watchdog, so the debug originally works well.
Thanks, all

It was not clear in your question that this occurred after halting in the debugger rather than in my mutual connection normal connection.  You would have got a quicker and more applicable answer had that been clear.  Too bad the cc2538 lacks the ability to suspend the watchdog timer when halted or an ability to detect a debugger connection so you can conditionally enable/disable it.  STM32 supports both - not that that helps you.

Based on my knowledge and experience, there's no way to step through code during debugging without halting the program's execution. The connection method I described in my question clearly states that I'm using a debugger with GDB (specifically JLinkDebugServer in this case), which automatically halts the core. Thank you for your explanation about the question misunderstanding in your previous reply. However, I'm afraid I can't agree with this comment.

Wow, I apologise, auto-correct really garbled my last comment.  That fist line should have just said "... rather than on initial connection".  However I certainly did not suggest the code could be stepped without halting!  The part that misled me was "When the gdb connection is established for Contiki-NG, it shows...", which suggests an issue with the debug connection in the first instance
